# How to populate Access Database Using Checkboxes?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to populate one column in an Access table using two check boxes - one for 0, one for 10. How do I make it so that on click or after update, whichever check box is checked populates the cell with the associated number?

Any assistance (if there's a better way to choose from two values?) would be much appreciated.

Regards,
Steve

Answer (score 2):

A check box does not seem to me appropriate for selecting between 0 and 10, since

1. you cannot bind it as such to field in your table
2. it is a control commonly associated with Yes/No values

I would rather go here with an Option group (if you have enough space) or with a combo box (drop down list).

You did not mention if the field is Required nor the type of field. If field is not Required (meaning it must handle Null value), go for the Combo.

Answer (score 0):

A toggle button is probably more what you're looking for. A drop down list would work as well.

Comment: Toggle is functionally equivalent to Checkbox, and not very suitable here, nor easy to implement IMHO, nor able to handle Nulls well.